# Errors with large data sources

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports, dataset, oracle10g

I'm doing some benchmarking on large data sources and binding/exporting data for reporting.

I started with using a data set, filling it with 100000 rows and then attempting to open a crystal report with the retrieved data.  I noticed that the data set filled just fine (took about 779 milliseconds) however, when attempting to export the data to the report or even bind to a gridview the application would fail with an OutOfMemoryException.

Does anyone experienced this before or have an idea of how to get around it?  It is very possible that clients will run reports for years worth of data and 100000 rows are not inconceivable.

The application and the benchmark code are written in C# using ORACLE and SQL Server databases.  I still have some data sources to test, but would like to know how to get around this just in case I don't find a better solution.

PLEASE BE AWARE THIS IS FOR REPORTING NOT ACTUAL GRID VIEW.

Comment: Are you able to benchmark what the tipping point is for OutOfMemory? 1000 rows, 10K, 50K?  In any case, consider the paging option for your users and your DB.

Comment: It bombs at 30000 rows.  I really dont want to use a grid view.  I tried it for testing to see if it would happen as well.  I really want to use this data in a report.  Is the paging option available for Crystal reports?

Answer (score 1):

No sane person would fill a gridview with 100000 rows. Implement paging or buy a component that offers paging out of the box if you are not sure how to do it

Comment: the issue is not only with grid views.  As a matter of fact this information isnt being used on a grid view at all.  It is being used to populate a Crystal report.  The grid view was for testing after the report threw the same exception.